# Easiest way to transform one map into another map using lambda expression in java

Tags: java, arrays

This question might seem similar to others but most of the ones I searched involved either copying one map into another or had a primitive data type.
The first map I have contains a Map of fileName and a list of tags that file contains.

```
Map<String, List<String>> map1
```

Now I want to transform the above `map1` so that it creates a map of tags with list of files which contain those tags.
I've achieved it using the traditional approach but I want something that's more efficient than creating a loop and iterating through the list.

```
Eg:- map1 = [{file1, [@tag1, @tag2]},{file2, [@tag3, @tag1]}]
--> 
map2 = [{@tag1, [file1, file2]}, {@tag2, [file1]}, {@tag3, [file2]}]
```

Comment: If you have working code that's complete, it should really be posted on Code Review. This site is primarily for fixing broken code. Post your current complete solution there, and they can help you tweak it to be more efficient.

Comment: I agree @Carcigenicate but I want to learn on how it can be done using Lambda expressions. I don't think showing SO the old fashion code would be of any help here.

Comment: Just be aware that you are asking for **TWO NOT NECESSARILY SAME** things: "using lambda" (I suppose that you rather mean using **Java 8 streams**) and "more efficient than creating a loop and iterating through the list". Very often we use streams+lambda not primarily to get *more efficient* code, but rather to get *more readable and more easily maintainable* code. I strongly believe that *in many cases* the good old loops are much more efficient than over-complicated streams constructs :)

Comment: Yup you are correct! I meant using streams to see how it can be done and with lambda expressions make it more readable just like you mentioned. But if the loops are more efficient than the streams I guess I will stick with the old is gold approach :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, with Java 8 streams, is map entries to pairs (String, String), then group them by one representing tag value and collect to map.

In this case, traditional approach might by more efficient.

```
Map<String, List<String>> map1 = new HashMap(){{
    put("file1", Arrays.asList("@tag1", "@tag2"));
    put("file2", Arrays.asList("@tag3", "@tag1"));
}};
Map<String, List<String>> map2 = map1.entrySet()
  .stream()
  .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue()
                         .stream()
                         .map(tag -> new SimpleEntry<>(tag, entry.getKey())))
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                          SimpleEntry::getKey,
                          Collectors.mapping(SimpleEntry::getValue, Collectors.toList()))
  );
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(map2.entrySet().toArray()));
```

Result is:

```
[@tag2=[file1], @tag3=[file2], @tag1=[file2, file1]]
```